# checking through a generated string for uppercase,lowercase,numbers and symbols

Tags: python

currently attempting to scan through an automatically generated string based on the length of a password , if the password does not contain an uppercase,lowercase, symbol and number a condtion should be triggered in the if statement in which will iterate until a string with the condtions is generated. however the iteration never stops despite whether an string meets its condtion or not.

im sure the error is in the while loop but i cannot figure out the problem with the while loop

code:

```
import random

passlen = int(input("Enter the length of password: \n"))

s="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
ss="01234567890"
sss="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
ssss="!@#$%^&*()"
comb = s+ss+sss+ssss
p =  "".join(random.sample(comb,passlen ))

while(s not in p and ss not in p and sss not in p and ssss not in p):
  
        p =  "".join(random.sample(comb,passlen ))
        print ("The generated password: ", p)
```

Comment: What is the condition `s not in p and ss not in p and sss not in p and ssss not in p` supposed to mean?

Comment: it is supposed to check if any of the characters in said strings are stored in the p string, so that there will have to be a minimum of each one in a string

Comment: If you want to ensure the password contains a character from each group, select a random character from each group, then pad with random characters from all, then shuffle. That will be easier, clearer, and probably faster than guess & check.

Comment: Not a solution but s, ss, sss, and ssss  are very confusing variable names. Conventionally, variable names are full words or multi-word phrases that explain what the variable does. Single character variable names are more or less reserved for loop indicies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks for the substrings "ABCD...XYZ", "abcd...xyz", "012...789", and the string listing out all the possible special characters. Unless you're trying to generate a password of length at least `26 + 26 + 10 + 10 = 72`, those substrings can never appear in your password, so your code loops infinitely.

Rejection sampling isn't necessary here. You can pick one character from each of your four categories, select the remaining characters from the combination of all four categories, and then shuffle the characters.

```py
import random

passlen = int(input("Enter the length of password: \n"))

lowercase_letters="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
numbers="01234567890"
uppercase_letters="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
special_characters="!@#$%^&*()"

combined_characters = lowercase_letters + uppercase_letters + numbers + special_characters

password_characters = []
for category in [lowercase_letters, numbers, uppercase_letters, special_characters]:
    password_characters.append(random.choice(category))

password_characters.extend(random.sample(combined_characters, passlen - 4))

random.shuffle(password_characters)
print("The generated password:", "".join(password_characters))
```

Comment: this works, i see where my error lay, will accept as answer

Comment: You might consider `choices` instead of `sample`. Allowing duplicates increases the key space.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expression.

```
import re

regex_pattern = re.compile('(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.{8,})')

password = 'Azerty123*^$'
if regex_pattern.search(password):
   print(True)
```